# Rails 3, inserting local IP address into record field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, ip

I have a Rails 3 application and I would like to add a field to one of my models, the field will be called something along the lines of localip.

How do I add the current local IP to the field?

The standard create method in the controller is like this:

```
# POST /prescriptions
  # POST /prescriptions.json
  def create
    @prescription = Prescription.new(params[:prescription])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @prescription.save
        format.html { redirect_to @prescription, notice: 'Prescription was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @prescription, status: :created, location: @prescription }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @prescription.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Is there some way of inserting it using the create method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by "current local IP" you mean IP of the client. 
If that's so then you can access this from env hash in your controller action -

```
current_local_ip = request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

or

```
current_local_ip = request.env['REMOTE_HOST']
```

And if you mean server's ip by current local ip, just look up the value of HTTP_HOST key.

Comment: How do I insert the value into the desired field in the model though?

Comment: assuming that your field is localip and it belongs to prescription model, all you need to do is `@prescription.localip = request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']` before you do `@prescription.save`

Comment: @nonocut This would be in it's respective Controller though, right?